# Bash built-in hash and command searching

Tags: linux, bash, shell, hash

What will happen when you type a command and it's not recognized as one of the internal commands ?
The usual answer you get is that bash will look for it from search path. Even recent professional text books offer you that answer.  Unfortunately that is not exactly what happens. 
Bash will check first its own built-in hash table for match and if no match goes to read search path contents and adds the path where executable was found into hash table.  The idea of using hash table in the first place is to avoid repeatedly searching the path and thus speeding up the things.  However, it may result in strange looking situations as we see in our test next.
We can see what's currently hashed by command:

```
hash
hash: hash table empty
```

You'll see that answer if you just opened your terminal.

Let's run "date" and see again:

```
date
Tue Jan 20 14:13:42 AST 2015
hash
hits    command
1   /bin/date
```

So far everything ok. Let's move now "date" to another location. We select a destination which is in search path:

```
sudo mv /bin/date /usr/bin/date
```

Let's check that we are still able to run "date", it should be found since the location is in search path:

```
date
bash: /bin/date: No such file or directory
```

Oops.  Bash is not trying to find from the search path at all when hash table search results a path (which is invalid now).

Functionality is described in
[Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html)

You can manually force "hash" to reload the new location of "date"

```
hash date
```

and everything is fine again.

Why bash is not able to search at `$PATH` when hash table returns invalid path for an executable ?

Comment: From the document you reference: "A full search of the directories in $PATH is performed only if the command is not found in the hash table."   An entry is found in the hash table, so PATH is not searched.

Comment: That design does not exactly make sense for me...Is there any reason for that design ?  Why not do search when returned path was not valid ?

Comment: There is a very reasonable expectation that commands will not be moved.  If they are moved, it is perfectly reasonable to restart the shell or simply rebuild the hash.

Comment: I agree anything can be done manually.

Comment: That's neither any major problem, rather a small idea for improvement and showing that feature for interested.

Comment: This is effectively a feature request, not a question about software development. It would be better as a post to the bash developer mailing list.

Answer (score 2):

> Why bash is not able to search at $PATH when hash table returns invalid path for an executable ?

It is because `bash` adds an entry in `hash` table ONLY when a command runs **successfully**.

If you got it earlier:

```
hash
hits  command
1     /bin/date
```

And then run something like:

```
qwerty
-bash: qwerty: command not found
```

Since `qwerty` command wasn't found, it won't be added in `hash` table. If you run `hash` again you will still get:

```
hash
hits  command
1     /bin/date
```

No entry of `qwerty` got added in table. So `bash` shell goes by assumption that if an entry is available in `hash` table (which is nothing but a cache) then that binary can be run again using that `hash` entry and `$PATH` won't be searched.

Comment: First time when it does not know about command it is able to _search_ but second time when it does not know about command it will give up without even trying _search_  ?  Search would result success.

Comment: Yes that is true, that is the whole purpose of `hash` table. If an entry is found in `hash` table then it will be reused.

Comment: Bash is able to search when something was not found as internal command. Why it's not able to search again when finding the command using hash table fails ?  That search would be successful and updating hash table corretly would result.

Comment: That's the way `bash` code has been written and seriously I don't see much wrong here as not many people would be moving binaries after they have run it once before. Anyway it is not adding not found entries in this table. And for those rare cases `hash -r` is there.

Comment: Anything can be done manually but the point is that update could be automatic.  Like I said, search would find correct executable and the contents of hash table would be updated corretly if bash were not giving up at that point.

Comment: Yes but your are questioning why `bash` code has been written that way, which can be changed they way are are suggesting if you suggest it to bash developers and they agree with this proposal.

Comment: I agree that feature is not any major problem, rather just a small thing that could possibly be improved.

Comment: Yes I agree with what you're saying but unfortunately don't see a way of achieving that in current bash versions.

Comment: Maybe in the future version ?  Nobody has had concerns about that improvement idea.

Comment: Yes they may decide to enhance `hash` feature in future versions

Answer (score 1):

That is how Bash is currently designed. An error message will be shown in that situation instead of attempting to find executable at search path $PATH.